# Supabase to React data fetch error - supabaseUrl is required

Tags: reactjs, supabase, supabase-database

I'm trying to set up my React app with Supabase for fetching data but everytime getting the error `Uncaught Error: supabaseUrl is required.`

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPXrH.png)

I've checked all the previous answers but still getting the error:

My `.env.local` file:

```
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL=https://eyd.....
REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY=eyJIUzI1Ni.....
```

My `supabase.js` file:

```
import { createClient } from "@supabase/supabase-js";

const supabaseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL;
const supabaseAnonKey = process.env.REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY;

export default createClient(supabaseUrl, supabaseAnonKey);
```

The file where I'm trying to fetch my data:

```js
import React from "react";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import supabase from "../supabase";

export default function BlogPosts() {
    async function fetchData() {
        let { data: bposts, error } = await supabase.from("bposts").select("*");
        console.log(bposts);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, []);
  
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(bposts, null, 2)}</pre>;

}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
SupabaseClient.ts:87 
        
       Uncaught Error: supabaseUrl is required.
    at new SupabaseClient (SupabaseClient.ts:87:1)
    at createClient (index.ts:38:1)
    at ./src/supabase.js (supabase.js:6:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/components/Blog/BlogCard.js (Blog.js:28:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
```

I've tried:

✅ restarted my dev instance

✅ rechecked the api values for `REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL` and `REACT_APP_SUPABASE_ANON_KEY`

✅ checked if the REACT_APP_SUPABASE_URL is the same at the .env file

But nothing helped. Looking for a solution, would appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 0):

If code is not able to access the env variable then try `require("dotenv").config();`

```
npm install dotenv
```

Comment: Add require line on the top of your js file